# Inserting data into spreadsheet with loop in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, openpyxl, spreadsheet

I tested a small example, openpyxl works fine.

But I have a problem in my main project.

There is a list of BeautifulSoup generated pages, I can get name and price of assets with print function. When I try to insert these data into excel file with loop, program crashes, file is created, but it is corrupted.

```
import requests, sys, bs4, locale, re, openpyxl, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from time import sleep

req = Request('https://coinmarketcap.com/exchanges/beaxy/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html_page = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')

#preparing an excel file
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb['Sheet']

#all beaxy exchange listed coins
#coinmarketcap URL pages of these coins
cryptoUrls = []

for url in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'title': True,'href': re.compile("^/currencies/")}):
    cryptoUrls.append('https://coinmarketcap.com' + url.get('href'))

# removing duplicate items
cryptoUrls = list(dict.fromkeys(cryptoUrls))

# Data of coinmarketcap URLs generated by BeautifulSoup
soup_list = []

for coinUrl in cryptoUrls:
    resp = requests.get(coinUrl, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        soup_list.append(bs4.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser'))
        sleep(2)

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8')

for idx, cryptoCoin in enumerate(soup_list,start=2):
    rowB = 'B{0}'.format(idx)
    rowC = 'C{0}'.format(idx)
    sheet[rowB] = cryptoCoin.body.h1(string=True)[0].strip()
    sheet[rowC] = locale.atof(cryptoCoin.select('.cmc-details-panel-price__price')[0].text.strip('$'))
else:
    wb.save('testcr.xlsx')
```

I couldn't find bug here. I would be very happy if you can help with this.

Thanks

Comment: Does Python throw any exception? If so, can you add the traceback.

Comment: @Shiva I am testing it on python shell, it restarts.

Comment: Try putting all your code in a file and execute it, you may be able to see the exception at least. I don't see any issues with the above code.

Comment: @Shiva There was a Deprecation Warning - Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use wb[sheetname]).
  sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet') ----- I changed line as **sheet = wb['Sheet']** but it still creates corrupted file.

Comment: Try saving the data as csv and open it with Excel. I doubt the DeprecationWarning is causing the issue but you can try fixing it as suggested.

Comment: @Shiva unfortunately it also didn't help, it creates empty file. I tried to assign simple string instead of beautiful soup data, but same problem is occured.

Comment: Can you show the complete code including beautiful soup related?

Comment: @Shiva Thank you very much for trying to help me. I updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

The only exception I faced while running the code was

```
Error: unsupported locale setting
```

on the line: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8')`

I changed it to `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')`(note the hyphen) and everything worked fine. I was able to open the excel file successfully.

My environment:
MacOS, Python 3.8

Comment: Thank you very much. I think problem is on my computer then, it also didn't help. I'll try it on a VPS asap.

Comment: Can you give details of your OS, Python version? In the meantime ensure you have the latest versions of `BeautifulSoup` and `openpyxl`. Btw, `sleep(2)` is not required.

Comment: Python 3.8.3 Windows 10. BeautifulSoup and openpyxl are latest versions. I use sleep(2) to avoid ddos protection.